# what happens if we input a character in a switch case where an integer is required in C

Tags: c

```
int main(void)  
{
```

'this is a code made by me so far'
        int select;
        do
        {
            system("CLS");
            printf("\n1]Add Student");
            printf("\n2]Display Students");
            printf("\n3]Search Student");
            printf("\n4]Sort Alphabetically");
            printf("\n5]Exit");
            printf("\nSelect Option: ");
            scanf("%d",&select);

```
        switch(select)
        {
            case 1: 
            .
            .
            break;
            .
            .
            .
            case 5:
            printf("\nGoodbye!");
            break;

            default:
            printf("\nSelect 1-5");
            break;          
        }   
        getch();
    }while(select != 5);
}
```

Comment: dont know about context but after scanf("%d",&select);   "**" that character shouldnt be existing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `scanf( "%d", &select);` will not read anything *but* a decimal integer from the input stream; if you enter a non-digit character, it won't be read from the input stream *at all* (meaning `select` won't be updated and `scanf` will return a value of 0).

Second, `case '1':` does not match against the integer value `1`, but against the value for the *character constant* `'1'` (decimal 48 in ASCII).  So if you enter `1` at your prompt, your code won't take the `case '1':` branch.

So, I suggest making the following changes:

```
do {
  // print menu as before

  while ( scanf( "%d", &select ) != 1 )
  {
    while ( getchar() != '\n' ) // remove everything up to the next newline
      ;
    printf( "Input a value between 1 and 5: " );
    fflush( stdout );  
  }

  switch( select )
  {
    case 1: // note no single quotes around 1
      ...
      break;

    case 2:
      ...
      break;

    ...
  }
} while ( select != 5 );
```

Comment: sorry to ask this question but what if i input 1 wouldnt be the program exits?

Comment: sir will you tell me the use of getchar() function and what library it belongs also the fflush(stdout);

Comment: @user5347510: both are declared in `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Since characters are actually a class of integer types, the number entered in is compared against the ASCII values of the switch cases.

In the case of `'1'`, its ASCII value is 49, so if you were to enter in 49 it would match the `'1'` case.

For this to work as expected, the cases would have to change to numbers instead of characters representing numbers, i.e. `case 1:` instead of `case '1':`.

Comment: case 1:   
            .  
            .  
            break;  
            .  
            .  
            .  
            case 5:  
            printf("\nGoodbye!");  
            break;

Comment: still it accepts character or a group of words after a cycle of the loop

Comment: @user5347510 What exactly does that mean?  What are you inputting, what is the result, and what do you expect?

Comment: i input 1 - 5 only but when i input a letter for example A or a group of words like iamhandsome the default must be the output

Comment: @user5347510: `scanf("%d", &select)` will not accept `A` as a valid input; it will leave the character in the input stream and return 0, and `select` will not be updated.

Comment: so what must I do to when i input a character the default must be displayed.

Comment: @user5347510 See John Bode's answer: you need to check the return value of `scanf`, and if it doesn't return 1 print the error message and clear the input buffer using `getchar()`.